# JSON - How to append an array to an array in sql

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a json field in a table that contains an array like this:-

```
[
  {
    "ID": 11111,
    "Name": "apple",
  },
  {
    "ID": 22222,
    "Name": "orange",
  },
  {
    "ID": 333333,
    "Name": "banana",
  } 
]
```

I would like to append/concatenate the following json array to this one:-

```
[
  {
    "ID": 44444,
    "Name": "grape",
  },
  {
    "ID": 55555,
    "Name": "kiwi",
  },
  {
    "ID": 66666,
    "Name": "fig",
  } 
]
```

So that I end up with this in the table field:-

```
[
  {
    "ID": 11111,
    "Name": "apple",
  },
  {
    "ID": 22222,
    "Name": "orange",
  },
  {
    "ID": 333333,
    "Name": "banana",
  },
  {
    "ID": 44444,
    "Name": "grape",
  },
  {
    "ID": 55555,
    "Name": "kiwi",
  },
  {
    "ID": 66666,
    "Name": "fig",
  } 
]
```

i.e. I've added the three new elements to the three existing elements so that i now have a single array with six elements in my table field.

I have been trying to make this work with JSON_MODIFY and have been successful in adding a single element to the array with something like this:-

```
select JSON_MODIFY(json_field,'append $', JSON_QUERY('{ "ID": 44444, "Name": "grape" }'))
```

But I cannot make it append more than one element in a single operation and make it look as desired, I've been trying variations of this:-

```
select JSON_MODIFY(json_field,'append $', JSON_QUERY('[{ "ID": 44444, "Name": "grape" }, { "ID": 55555, "Name": "kiwi" }, { "ID": 66666, "Name": "fig" }]'))
```

In this particular case, it appended it with the square brackets so the three new elements ended up being a sub-array!

Is it possible to get append multiple elements of one array to another like this? (Am I being really thick and missing something obvious?!?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Example - Multiple updates: With JSON_MODIFY you can update only one
> property. If you have to do multiple updates, you can use multiple
> JSON_MODIFY calls.

This would mean looping, something I'd try to avoid...

I'd suggest either a simple string action or de-composition/re-composition:

```
DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'[
  {
    "ID": 11111,
    "Name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "ID": 22222,
    "Name": "orange"
  },
  {
    "ID": 333333,
    "Name": "banana"
  } 
]'; 
DECLARE @json2 NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'[
  {
    "ID": 44444,
    "Name": "grape"
  },
  {
    "ID": 55555,
    "Name": "kiwi"
  },
  {
    "ID": 66666,
    "Name": "fig"
  } 
]';
```

--This will re-create the JSON out of derived tables

```
SELECT t.ID,t.[Name]
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json1) WITH(ID int,[Name] NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json2) WITH(ID int,[Name] NVARCHAR(MAX))
) t
FOR JSON PATH;
```

--This will create a *naked array* and `STUFF()` it into the correct position

```
DECLARE @NakedArray NVARCHAR(MAX)=N',' +
(
    SELECT A.* 
    FROM OPENJSON(@json2)
    WITH(ID int, Name NVARCHAR(MAX)) A
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
);

SELECT STUFF(@json1,LEN(@json1)-1,0,@NakedArray);
```

The *naked array* you could achieve simply by replacing the `[` with a comma and cut away the `]` too...

### UPDATE: A minimal approach

Try this minimal approach:

```
SELECT REPLACE(@json1,']',REPLACE(@json2,'[',','));
```

Comment: The minimal approach is very nifty :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, one never fails to learn something new. (Deleted my answer because yours does the same thing.)

Comment: wow, thanks everyone for such quick responses!! i made the post yesterday evening my time then went straight out to dinner, then didn't check it again until i got back in a few hours later thinking no-one would have even read it let alone answered it (i am new to stackoverflow, been using other forums in the past where responses have been a wee bit slower ;-).

anyways back to the answers - doh! i totally thought you could do this with json_modify and i was just missing the obvious (even tho the obvious was actually the docs telling me it couldn't be done!).

Comment: using union sounds ideal, but i really do like the simplicity of the minimal approach so i will use that and keep union in reserve as i have lots of json crud to do so i am sure it will come in useful :)

Comment: The approaches work for simple cases like the one in the question but do not work for arrays of arbitrary objects. The minimal approach is indeed nifty but will fail when the arrays to be combined contain string values with [ or ] and/or inner arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @j1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[
  {
    "ID": 11111,
    "Name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "ID": 22222,
    "Name": "orange"
  },
  {
    "ID": 333333,
    "Name": "banana"
  } 
] ';


DECLARE @j2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
[
  {
    "ID": 44444,
    "Name": "grape"
  },
  {
    "ID": 55555,
    "Name": "kiwi"
  },
  {
    "ID": 66666,
    "Name": "fig"
  } 
] ';


SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT [ID], [Name] FROM  OPENJSON(@j1) WITH (ID INT, [Name] NVARCHAR(200))
UNION
SELECT  [ID], [Name]  FROM  OPENJSON(@j2) WITH (ID INT, [Name] NVARCHAR(200))
) x
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Comment: I voted your's up, as you were faster by seconds, but you might check my last line ;-) this seems to be the easiest ...

Comment: ah, i have just discovered that i cannot mark this as an answer as well as Shnugo's, guess that makes sense to only have one answer maximum. 

i am not sure whose to give the tick to now as both answers have what i would guess is the proper way to do it using union, but i think i should prob leave it as Shnugo's since i will be using the minimal answer - is that the correct way to do it? apologies, i am not sure of the protocol here. in any case, @mike123 many thanks for the quick response as well :)

Comment: @dan0001 - Shnugo have helped me with the answer. He deserves the credit :)

Comment: The approach works for simple cases like the one in the question but do not work for arrays of arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the same problem. And I found my solution very uncivilized. But it seems there's nothing better.

```
SELECT CONCAT(STUFF(@json1,LEN(@json1),1,','),STUFF(@json2,1,1,''))
```

Answer (score -1):

The following expands previous solutions to work for the union of JSON arrays of arbitrary objects/arrays/values, even when string values contain the characters [ or ].  However the solution uses the STRING_AGG function, thus requiring SQL Server 2017 and later.

```
    DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'[
  {
    "ID": 11111,
    "Name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "ID": 22222,
    "Number": 1234
  },
  {
    "ID": 333333,
    "Names": ["apple", "banana"]
  } 
]'; 
DECLARE @json2 NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'[
  {
    "Random": "grape"
  },
  [
    123,
    456
  ],
  "f[i]g"
]';

SELECT CONCAT(
    N'[',
        (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(U.[value],N',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY U.ArrayNo ASC,U.[key] ASC)
            FROM
                (
                SELECT 1 AS ArrayNo,[key],[value] FROM OPENJSON(@JSON1)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 2 AS ArrayNo,[key],[value] FROM OPENJSON(@JSON2)
                ) AS U
            ),
    N']'
    )
```